# Publish Actions and Share on Facebook Page at the same time is not working

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-opengraph

We launched Facebook Timeline integration some days ago. Further to our users' feedbacks, I have a question. It's quite amazing, but this is what I found:

When I do a "publish_action" almost at the same time as a "Share on Facebook Page" (with the same URL to share), I see that my "Share on Facebook Page" does not work and I get the following error:

```
 Facebook responded with HTTP status code 400 and response body: 
 {"error":{"message":"(#1500) The url you supplied invalid","type":"OAuthException","code":1500}}
```

When the "Share on Facebook Page" is made after the "publish_action" (by after, I mean 30sec), it's working like a charm.

The URL is indeed valid (just because the "publish_action" is well working)

Do you have any idea about that ?

***MAY 3 UPDATE***

I've created a bug on facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/284272281663170 
To be continued...